# Как наследовать по прототипу javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

Использую методы по этому ресурсу https://learn.javascript.ru/class-inheritance

```
function hot3() {

    this.has = 10;
  }

function hot2 () {
   this.desc = 'some';
 }


hot2.prototype = Object.create(hot3.prototype);

var f = new hot2();
console.log(f.has);
```

Не могу получить свойство через прототип ответ undefined

Comment: Ну как минимум строка "this.has = 10;" ни разу в этом коде не выполняется, поскольку не вызывается конструктор. Но проблема не в этом :-) hot3.prototype.has = 10; сработает, но я не могу объяснить почему ваш код не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`has` не является свойством `hot3.prototype`. Вы должны явно вызывать конструктор родителя из конструктора `hot2`.

```js
function hot3() {
    this.has = 10;
  };

function hot2 () {
  hot3.apply(this); // вызов конструктора

  this.desc = 'some';
 };

hot2.prototype = Object.create(hot3.prototype);
hot2.prototype.constructor = hot2; // на всякий случай

var f = new hot2();
alert(f.has);
```

Comment: но это уже не прототипное наследование а функциональный паттерн наследования, в вашем решении нет смысла использовать prototype вообще

Comment: @modelfak вы читали первую строчку ответа? has задается в конструкторе hot3. Этот конструктор при наследовании через прототип не вызывается. Или вызывайте его руками, или сделайте has частью прототипа, или используйте has в hot2. Я же просто привел вам код из вашего же туториала, из раздела `Вызов конструктора родителя`.

Comment: спасибо, за помощь